# The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets despite being in Connection String

Tags: sql, asp.net, ado.net

My connection string is as follows, in my Web.config:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <clear />
    <add name="Northwind_DB" connectionString="Data Source=dataSource; Initial Catalog=initialCatalog; MultipleActiveResultSets=True; Persist Security Info=True; User ID=userID; Password=password;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

As you can see, I have MultipleActiveResultSets=True in my ConnectionStrings, and yet I still receive the error "The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets" when trying to run my code.

Here is the code throwing the error:

```
    SqlConnection Conn;
    SqlCommand Command1 = new SqlCommand();
    SqlCommand Command2 = new SqlCommand();
    SqlDataReader Reader1;
    SqlDataReader Reader2;
    IAsyncResult ASyncResult1;
    IAsyncResult AsyncResult2;

    System.Threading.WaitHandle[] WHandles = new
    System.Threading.WaitHandle[2];
    System.Threading.WaitHandle WHandle1;
    System.Threading.WaitHandle WHandle2;

    Conn = new SqlConnection();
    Conn.ConnectionString =
    ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Northwind_DB"].ConnectionString;

    Command1.CommandText = "SQL statement is here.";

    Command1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Command1.Connection = Conn;

    Command2.CommandText = "SQL statement is here";

    Command2.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    Command2.Connection = Conn;

    Conn.Open();

    AsyncResult1 = CustCommand.BeginExecuteReader();
    ASyncResult2 = OrdersCommand.BeginExecuteReader();

    WHandle1 = AsyncResult1.AsyncWaitHandle;
    WHandle2 = ASyncResult2.AsyncWaitHandle;

    WHandles[0] = WHandle1;
    WHandles[1] = WHandle2;

    System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAll(WHandles);

    DataReader1 = Command1.EndExecuteReader(AsyncResult1);
    DataReader2 = Command2.EndExecuteReader(ASyncResult2);

    gvData1.DataSource = Reader1;
    gvData1.DataBind();

    gvData2.DataSource = Reader2;
    gvData2.DataBind();

    Conn.Close();
```

I'm not sure what is causing this code to fail, what am I doing wrong in regards to enabling Multiple Active Results Sets in my code? I originally got the answer to put it in my ConnectionString from various other threads on this website, but it hasn't worked for me, unfortunately.

Comment: Just for a quick check. What is the NET Framework version in use here?

Comment: @Steve, 4.0 is the Framework, sorry for the late reply.

Comment: what's your sql server version? very old ones might not support MARS ...